# Splitting of ethyl ester proton NMR

Tags: organic-chemistry, nmr-spectroscopy

I synthesised a dihydropyridine molecule today and recieved my NMR. I am wondering where the complex splitting for the 7 and 22 protons is coming from.
My spectrum:

- 1.26ppm, triplet, 6H
- 2.33ppm, singlet, 6H
- **4.16ppm, multiplet, 4H**
- 5.20ppm, singlet, 1H
- 5.65ppm, singlet, 1H
- 5.94ppm, doublet of doublets, 1H
- 6.21ppm, doublet of triplets, 1H
- 7.21ppm, singlet, 1H

Here is the multiplet form 4.16ppm:

[image]

The molecule:

[image]

Thanks very much!

Comment: The protons at 7 and 22 are diastereotopic because of the stereogenic center at 9. The hydrogens at the -CH2- are non-equivalent, have different chemical shifts and couple with each other in each -CH2-. Look here: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/95027/magnetic-non-equivalence-of-acetal-protons/95044#95044

Comment: On closer inspection C9 is non-stereogenic but that doesn't change the argument. Each methylene has -CH(a)H(b).